# can logstash process multiple output simultaneously?

Tags: logstash

i'm very new to logstash and elastic search. I am trying to store log files both in elasticsearch and a flat file. I know that logstash support both output. But are they processed simultaneously? or is it done periodically through a job?

Answer (score 6):

Yes you can do this like so by tagging and cloning your inputs with the "add_tag" command on your shipper config.

```
input
{
    tcp     { type => "linux" port => "50000" codec => plain { charset => "US-ASCII" } }
    tcp     { type => "apache_access" port => "50001" codec => plain { charset => "US-ASCII" } }
    tcp     { type => "apache_error"  port => "50002" codec => plain { charset => "US-ASCII" } }
    tcp     { type => "windows_security" port => "50003" codec => plain { charset => "US-ASCII" } }
    tcp     { type => "windows_application" port => "50004" codec => plain { charset => "US-ASCII" } }
    tcp     { type => "windows_system" port => "50005" codec => plain { charset => "US-ASCII" } }
udp { type => "network_equipment" port => "514" codec => plain { charset => "US-ASCII" } }
udp { type => "firewalls" port => "50006" codec => plain }
}
filter
{
    grok    { match => [ "host", "%{IPORHOST:ipaddr}(:%{NUMBER})?" ] }
    mutate  { replace => [ "fqdn", "%{ipaddr}" ] }
    dns     { reverse => [ "fqdn", "fqdn" ] action => "replace" }
    if [type] == "linux"                    { clone { clones => "linux.log" add_tag => "savetofile" } }
    if [type] == "apache_access"            { clone { clones => "apache_access.log" add_tag => "savetofile" } }
    if [type] == "apache_error"             { clone { clones => "apache_error.log" add_tag => "savetofile" } }
    if [type] == "windows_security"         { clone { clones => "windows_security.log" add_tag => "savetofile" } }
    if [type] == "windows_application"      { clone { clones => "windows_application.log" add_tag => "savetofile" } }
    if [type] == "windows_system"           { clone { clones => "windows_system.log" add_tag => "savetofile" } }
    if [type] == "network_equipment"        { clone { clones => "network_%{fqdn}.log" add_tag => "savetofile" } }
if [type] == "firewalls"        { clone { clones => "firewalls.log" add_tag => "savetofile" } }
}
output
{
    #stdout { debug => true }
    #stdout { codec => rubydebug }
    redis   { host => "1.1.1.1" data_type => "list" key => "logstash" }
}
```

And on your main logstash instance you would do this:

```
input {
    redis {
    host => "1.1.1.1" 
    data_type => "list" 
    key => "logstash" 
    type=> "redis-input"
    # We use the 'json' codec here because we expect to read json events from redis.
    codec => json
          }
    }
    output
    {
        if "savetofile" in [tags] {
            file {
                path => [ "/logs/%{fqdn}/%{type}" ] message_format => "%{message}"   
            } 
        }
        else { elasticsearch { host => "2.2.2.2" }
    }
}
```

Comment: In your example, logstash would output the specified "savetofile" logs to disk and other logs to elasticsearch. Is it possible to output the same logs to both outputs at the same time?

Answer (score 0):

FYI, You can study [The life of logstash event](http://logstash.net/docs/1.3.2/life-of-an-event) about the logstash event.

> The output worker model is currently a single thread. Outputs will receive events in the order they are defined in the config file.

But the Outputs may decide to buffer events temporarily before publishing them. Ex: Output will buffers 2 or 3 events then just it write to file.

Answer (score 0):

First you need to install output plugins:

```
/usr/share/logstash/bin/logstash-plugin install logstash-output-elasticsearch
/usr/share/logstash/bin/logstash-plugin install logstash-output-file
```

Then create conf files for output:

```
cat /etc/logstash/conf.d/nfs-output.conf

output {
  file {
    path => "/your/path/filebeat-%{+YYYY-MM-dd}.log"
  }
}


cat /etc/logstash/conf.d/30-elasticsearch-output.conf

output {
  elasticsearch {
    hosts => ["elasitc_ip:9200"]
    manage_template => true
    user => "elastic"
    password => "your_password"
  }
}
```

Then:

```
service logstash restart
```