# Listening on multiple UDP ports on logstash

Tags: logstash

I have a simple ELK setup to run on a single machine, to read custom-formatted log messages using Logstash and to analyse the data using Elasticsearch/Kibana.

Based off of the config files in one of the replies to [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20130864/can-logstash-process-multiple-output-simultaneously) stackoverflow post, I added multiple udp input entries in my conf file, part of which is shown here:

```
input {
  udp {
    type => "log_type_1"
    port => 9999
  }
  udp {
    type => "log_type_2"
    port => 9998
  }
  udp {
    type => "log_type_3"
    port => 9997
  }
}
```

When I re-start the logstash service and check the logs under `/var/log/logstash/logstash`, I see error messages with the message:

```
{:timestamp=>"2015-02-17T18:15:56.032000-0800", :message=>"UDP listener died", :exception=>#<SocketError: bind: name or service not known>, :backtrace=>["org/jruby/ext/socket/RubyUDPSocket.java:160:in `bind'", "/opt/logstash/lib/logstash/inputs/udp.rb:69:in `udp_listener'", "/opt/logstash/lib/logstash/inputs/udp.rb:50:in `run'", "/opt/logstash/lib/logstash/pipeline.rb:163:in `inputworker'", "/opt/logstash/lib/logstash/pipeline.rb:157:in `start_input'"], :level=>:warn}
```

Any ideas as to what I'm doing wrong over here? I tried running logstash using the `--configtest` flag and I don't see any problems with my configuration. I'm guessing it checks only for syntax correctness.

Thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Turns out that multiple UDP ports *are* in fact supported (no reason not to). A simple

`netstat -alp | grep <port_number>`

showed me that the ports we currently in use, and I managed to fix the issue by changing the port numbers around.

Thanks!